# Does Jesus Christ exist in the Dragon Ball universe?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball

In episode 70 of the original Dragon Ball series, Krillin fights one of Fortuneteller Baba's minions, who is a vampire. After he's defeated, Oopa and Puar jump in, and they manage to defeat him.

To do this, Oopa stands like a cross, stating that vampires can't stand crosses. In the next angle, the vampire is shown panicking, as he pictures a crucifix over Oopa, which starts to radiate light with organ music playing, as the words "Jesus Christ!!" and "Oh God!!" scroll across the screen.

In order for a vampire to be afraid of a crucifix, then the religious aspect of it must exist in universe, and the scrolling text seems to confirm this. Therefore, I'm wondering: **Does Jesus Christ exist in the Dragon Ball Universe?**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question would be a **no**!

Jesus Christ doesn't exist in the Dragon Ball Universe. *However*, there are multiple  **Real Life references/ Fictional works that exist in reality** which have been referenced on the show. A few other examples apart from the one you stated would be:

- The entire Pilaf Saga being a loose adaptation of *Journey to the West*, a famous Novel from Ming-era China.
- When Krillin kicks General Blue in the face without enough force to make his nose bleed and Blue complains about the Bleeding and compares it to the action of *throwing red paint on the Mono Lisa*.
- There's a grocery bag which says *"Super Mario"* on it, in Chapter 71 in the manga when Krillin and Launch come back to the Kame house.

I have attached a list [here](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_real_life_references) with more similar references with regard to the same.

Comment: You can also point out [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29186/what-are-the-many-references-dragon-ball-series-makes-to-other-franchises-people) regarding real life references ;)