# What are the anime/manga references in Gintama

Tags: gintama

In the anime of Gintama, there are several references made directly or indirectly to other works in anime and manga.
for example in the first/second episode they make a reference to Ashita no Joe, similarly Itachi's quote from Naruto is used in episode 25.

I would like to know what are the works that gintama makes references to in order to fully understand the parody they are doing.

Comment: I feel like this is too broad. There's simply so many references I don't think it would work for this format.

Comment: I agree with Michael : this kind of question is too broad unless you answer it yourself (see [Dragon Ball](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29186/what-are-the-many-references-dragon-ball-series-makes-to-other-franchises-people/), [Sora No Otoshimono](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28451/what-are-the-reference-of-heavens-lost-property-to-the-greek-mythology) or [Elfen Lied](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15130/about-the-artworks-used-in-the-elfen-lied-opening-scenes-contains-nudity))

Comment: @Ikaros your point makes sense, I will add a self answer as well detailing the references. Astral Sea's Answer does provide a very good list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are hardly any lists around that list them by episode, but if you want the lists, there is one on the [wikia](http://gintama.wikia.com/wiki/Parodies), though it is complete, it just lists them.

However, a better one, albeit being a little incomplete is available on [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ShoutOut/Gintama). This list is incomplete but it lists them in order according to the references.